# NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to ruby on rails and trying to learn by doing a blog web application, when I try to create an article and include a category to it, I get the error (NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass).
When I don't include the category and just create the article things seems to be working fine. I'm not sure what could possibly be wrong, could someone please help?

Here is My db schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160322060108) do

create_table "article_categories", force: true do |t|
  t.integer "article_id"
  t.integer "category_id"
end

  create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title",               limit: nil
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "username",        limit: nil
    t.string  "email",           limit: nil
    t.string  "password_digest", limit: nil
    t.boolean "admin",                       default: false
  end
end
```

category model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :article_categories
  has_many :articles, through: :article_categories  

  validates :name, presence: true, length:{ minimum: 3, maximum: 25}
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "270x179>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :article_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :article_categories
  validates :title, presence: true, length:{ minimum: 3, maximum: 60}
  validates :description, presence: true, length:{ minimum: 10}

  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/missing.jpg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

article_category model:

```
class ArticleCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :category
end
```

articles_controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_article, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
  before_action :require_user, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :require_same_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @articles = Article.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.user = current_user
    if @article.save
      flash[:success] = "Article was successfully created"
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @article.update(article_params)
      flash[:success] = "Article was successfully updated"
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    flash[:danger] = "Article was successfully deleted"
    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description, :avatar, category_ids: [])
    end

    def require_same_user
      if current_user != @article.user and !current_user.admin?
        flash[:danger] = "You can only edit or delete your own articles"
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end

end
```

and categories_controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_admin, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @categories = Category.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 9)
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    if @category.update(category_params)
      flash[:success] = "Category name was successfully updated"
      redirect_to category_path(@category)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    if @category.save
      flash[:success] = "Category was created successfully"
      redirect_to categories_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category_articles = @category.articles.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end

  private
    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name, :avatar)
    end

    def require_admin
      if !logged_in? && (logged_in? and !current_user.admin?)
        flash[:danger] = "Only admins can perform that action"
        redirect_to categories_path
      end
    end

end
```

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WksjN.jpg)

Comment: where did you got error? can you put the logs.

Comment: why not add `article_id` field to your category table so that you can relate your tables

Comment: just added the terminal picture aldrien.h

Comment: could you provide your `category_params` when you try create `@article` ?

Comment: it's in the bottom of categories_controller, under the private section

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of the filter. Remove before_action in all controller and try

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was Ruby version, changed the version to ruby 2.1 and now things are working.